# Bomb based alchemist builds

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-creation, alchemist

I'm looking for help with building a bomb-slinging alchemist at level 10.  Assume 25 point buy for initial generation.  **The focus is getting the most effective bomb usage possible.**  Fast bombs is clearly desired the moment it becomes a legal choice allowing for multiple attacks due to BAB progression, rapid shot feat, and possibly other options.  Source options are Core, Advanced Players Guide, Ultimate Magic, and Ultimate Combat.  **Which class-related options should I be considering?**  I do not need a complete character build.

Comment: Are you looking for options or wanting people to make you a build?  Your question isn't clear on that.

Comment: I had an incredibly fun time with my alchemist a couple of games ago. I loosely followed this guide: http://pathfinder.ogrehut.com/2010/07/dr-strangelob/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's important to note that (with Fast Bombs) you *can* throw bombs with both hands if you get the Two Weapon Fighting feats, and this stacks with Rapid Shot.  This lets a 10th level alchemist throw five bombs a round at +3/+3/+3/-2/-2 (before adding Dex or point-blank).  Not very high, but you don't need that high a bonus.  Personally I'd go this route before going for Rapid Shot, simply because you can continue gaining more attacks as you spend more feats.

You're also likely to want [dispelling bombs](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist/discoveries/paizo---alchemist-discoveries/dispelling-bomb) for the sheer utility.

Comment: Also forgot to mention, if you combine TWF, Rapid Shot, and dispel, you're effectively going "I strip away *all* your buffs in one turn" instead of the usual mage's one dispelled spell per turn.  It's pretty close to casting targeted greater dispel. Of course, you give up a lot of damage to actually do it.

Comment: @ColinD - Very true.  I didn't mention it originally because the OP already had, but I just edited in a reference to it.

Answer (score 26):

I have a player who is doing just this kind of build, so I think I can help you a little.

**Feats**

You don't have a lot of options when related to combat feats. The following you should consider your main focus:

- [Point-Blank Shot](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/point-blank-shot-combat---final) : Because it is a prerequisite to:
- [Precise Shot](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/precise-shot-combat---final): You don't want a -4 even though you're trying to hit touch AC most of the time.
- [Extra Discovery](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/extra-discovery): Because a lot of your awesomeness will come from your discoveries.
- [Extra Bombs](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/extra-bombs): Everyone loves more bombs.

(Important to note, [Deadly Aim](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/deadly-aim-combat) *does not work with bombs*)

**Discoveries**

- [Precise Bombs](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist/discoveries/paizo---alchemist-discoveries/precise-bombs): Hitting your allies is a quick way to getting yourself murdered by your party.
- [Smoke Bomb](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist/discoveries/paizo---alchemist-discoveries/smoke-bomb): Mostly because you need this to get:
- [Stink Bomb](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist/discoveries/paizo---alchemist-discoveries/stink-bomb): Because when your enemies are vomiting, they can't attack you.
- [Force Bomb](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist/discoveries/paizo---alchemist-discoveries/force-bomb): When everyone else is doing 1/2 damage to incorporeal things, you'll be laughing at them. Added bonus? It will knock them prone if they fail a Reflex save.
- [Fast Bombs](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist/discoveries/paizo---alchemist-discoveries/fast-bombs): Like you said, you need this when you hit more attacks per round.
- [Confusion Bomb](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist/discoveries/paizo---alchemist-discoveries/confusion-bomb-su): When your enemies are confused, there's a 75% chance per round they're doing something that doesn't hurt you (because you should be in the back).
- [Cognitogen](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist/discoveries/paizo---alchemist-discoveries/cognatogen-su): Your damage is based on Int. Pump your damage!

**Attributes**

Arguably, Alchemists are a 1 attribute class. This is Intelligence. Your bombs per day and additional bomb damage are based off of this. Bump it fairly high at the beginning and then put a little into Dex, so you can reliably hit Touch AC and a little into Con, so you're not super-squishy.

**General Advice**

You'll be aiming for Touch AC most of the time, so you don't need to worry too much about whether or not you're going to hit them. Plus if they have a touch AC which is too high to hit, you can simply [target a grid intersection (AC 5)](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Throw-Splash-Weapon) and just do splash damage to your foes.

Additionally, get some means of Flight, so that you can drop bombs on your enemies from above, and laugh when they only have melee weapons.

Comment: Flight is easy to achieve on an alchemist. It is on their forumulae list and wings can be achieved through a discovery.

Answer (score -2):

Alchemists don't get to throw extra bombs by taking two weapon fighting, it is listed as a standard action to create making the most you can throw per round 3 via Rapid Shot and the Fast Bombs discovery unless under the affect of a Haste spell or something similar. To maximize damage I suggest Clustered Shots + Targeted Bomb Admixture + Cognatogen. As a lvl 12 Elf Mindchemist I deal 6d6+20+1d6 acid from Acid Bombs per bomb throwing at 15/15/15/10 with their DR being added after all 4 bombs.

Comment: "Alchemists don't get to throw extra bombs by taking two weapon fighting" Uh, yes, With Fast Bombs, they do. http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fn#v5748eaic9n8l